# Http request succeed when using postman, fails when using node.js axios

Tags: node.js, api, axios

I have deployed BeaconCtrl project on heroku, it has a server to server api,
I tried requesting some routes using postman, with the same headers, body and the same route, it responds with 500 internal server error !.
does requesting from server to another server differ from requesting from postman to a server ?

Comment: You could be running into access-control-allow-origin issues. If thats the case you need to add some response headers to the server you are making the request to, to allow different origin servers

Comment: actually some routes works fine both with postman and axios @KeirLavelle